# How to protect text from being split by a float?

Tags: floats, positioning

Given following situation:

```
\begin{figure}[ht!]
    ...
\end{figure}
\begin{equation}
    ...    
\end{equation}
Some one-line text.
\begin{eqnarray}
    ...
    ...
\end{eqnarray}
```

how can I make sure that the float doesn't get placed between the equation and the equation array? Also the part to protect goes over two pages, if that's of any importance.

Comment: You should not use `eqnarray` since it has incorrect spacing and may print over the equation number. Use `align` instead.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

- The `placeins` package gives the command `\FloatBarrier`, which will make sure any floats will be put in before this point.
- The `flafter` package ensures that floats don't appear until after they appear in the code.

This means that you could use something like:

```
\usepackage{placeins} % put this in your pre-amble
\usepackage{flafter}  % put this in your pre-amble

...
\begin{figure}[ht!]
...
\end{figure}
\FloatBarrier % new bit
\begin{equation}
...    
\end{equation}
Some one-line text.
\begin{eqnarray}
...
...
\end{eqnarray}
% with the flafter package, this figure won't appear before this point
\begin{figure}[ht!]
...
\end{figure}
```

On another note, you might like to see this post:
[eqnarray vs align](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/196/eqnarray-vs-align)

Comment: Seems to work fine. Thanks for the link! While eqnarray doesn't cause any issues in my current work, I'll keep in mind that there are some drawbacks and will use align in the future.

Comment: You're welcome; I made an edit to include the `flafter` package, which might also be of interest.

Comment: FloatBarrier is all nice and well but it puts an additional constraint on figure placement that was not asked for not required to fulfil the aim of not splitting the list: Latex can no longer place the figure after an un-split list, which might be a better figure placement.