# Prevent float from splitting paragraph

Tags: floats, positioning, paragraphs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to protect text from being split by a float?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25917/how-to-protect-text-from-being-split-by-a-float)

I have this LaTeX like code

```
\begin{figure}...\end{figure}

[my paragraph text]
```

The output is

```
my paragraph 
------ <new page>
[Figure]
text
```

Essentially because the figure won't fit at the bottom of the page it goes to the top of the next page. BUT latex decides to place half of the paragraph text at the bottom of the page. I want

```
------ <newpage>
[Figure]
my paragraph text
```

I do not want the figure to "split" the paragraph in the middle. It looks wrong the way it is. I simply want the paragraph to be below the figure the way I typed it in LaTeX.

Comment: So you want empty space at the bottom of the preceding page? I can imagine that that will also "look wrong"

Comment: Sounds like http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8625/force-figure-placement-in-text, but as Jake says there are issues placing a large item 'here'.

Comment: @jake, it's only 2 lines... so I doubt will look as wrong as it is. My paragraph is 3 lines and the figure is splitting the last line. Anyways, what your saying is you don't know the solution?

Comment: @JosephWright I've tried various things like htb! and H and nothing works. The figure must be placed on the next page else it will be chopped off. The problem is that latex is pushing the next paragraph up to the previous page.

Comment: @Jake Aggressive voice? I was just making it clear you did not have a solution. Your statement was about how wrong the solution would look if it had one... yet you provided no solution to even check and do not know how wrong it looks already. I'd rather have the ability to see if the "wrong solution" was more or less wrong than the way it is.

Comment: sounds to me like you simply want to start a new page. Won't a simple `\newpage` (or a `\clearpage` to be sure the float is placed on the next page) work?

Comment: @Jake Yes, but it is not up to you to decide what is wrong or right for me. If you provided me with a solution I would try it and see if it would look right to me. After all, It's my project and I have the right to decide if it looks correct or not, don't I?

Comment: @cgnieder Yes, that would work BUT if I add/enlarge stuff above it then I'll end up with something probably much worse.

Comment: If you're text/document isn't ready yet why worry about float placement at all?

Comment: @cgnieder lol, well, that might be true but I could fix the problem now too. It may take care of itself in the future IF I add more text BUT if I don't then it will still be wrong. I don't see why it is so hard to prevent the figure from splitting a paragraph. Seems like it would be an easy solution ;/

Comment: I really don't see any problem (but I might be blind…): either the issue solves itself because you're adding text, or it doesn't and then you can use `\newpage`. Or did I get anything wrong?

Comment: It's not the figure that splits the paragraph: It's the page breaking algorithm. The figure is only there because you allowed figures at the top of the page. So if you want to disallow this you will have to prevent latex from inserting a page break in the paragraph. See `http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=nopagebrk` or disallow figures at the top of the page.

Comment: looks a lot like [how-to-protect-text-from-being-split-by-a-float](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25917/how-to-protect-text-from-being-split-by-a-float)

Comment: @AbstractDissonance -- in a comment, you say the split paragraph is only 3 lines.  that means you allow widows (and probably club lines, one line of a paragraph at the bottom of a page).  to disallow widows, use `\widowpenslty=10000`; similarly, `\clubpwnalty=10000`.  the default values for both = 150.  so you could even set the higher penalties before the paragraph, and reset them to the default later on after the paragraph is safely output.

Comment: @barbarabeeton What I used was `\FloatBarrier` which seems to keep my floats in order that they are shown.