# Prevent figures from breaking lists, paragraphs and stay in current section

Tags: floats, positioning, lists, paragraphs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to protect text from being split by a float?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25917/how-to-protect-text-from-being-split-by-a-float)

I have quite some images in my report and I insert them with this command I made:

```
\newcommand{\image}[3]{\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=1]{#1}
\caption{#2\label{#3}}
\centering
\end{figure}}
```

Now, there are a few things that I don't want. I don't want these images to suddenly appear in an itemisation/enumeration, I'd like it if they don't break paragraphs (above or under it is OK)  and if possible also in the section I wrote the code in.

First I used the `h` option (here), but I read you should let LaTeX manage those things and I'm OK with that except the things I listed.

Comment: looks pretty similar to [how-to-protect-text-from-being-split-by-a-float/](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25917/how-to-protect-text-from-being-split-by-a-float/25923#25923), let us know if it is different

Comment: Well, the image is allowed to be placed between 2 lists, just not between it's items.

Comment: as in the linked answer, use `\FloatBarrier` before the environment, and load `flafter` package

Comment: It's better, but there are a few places now where latx only writes text until half the page, leaves a lot of empty place and then puts it at the bottom of the page... Maybe the 'h' option is better sometimes?

Comment: never use h on its own, but if h is an acceptable position you can use [htp] or some such, it isn't really feasible to stop top floats coming mid-paragraph though if they fit at the top of the page LaTex doesn't know at that stage how the page break relates to the paragraph end

Comment: You should have a look at [How to influence the position of float environments like figure and table in LaTeX?](http://goo.gl/Qzz31) and 
[Keeping tables/figures close to where they are mentioned](http://goo.gl/290dD), which is concerned with float placement/positioning relative to the document content.

Comment: Have you ever tried the [`placeins`](http://ctan.org/pkg/placeins)  package for the last problem?

Comment: Yes, I ended up using the Float package and H option on some figures that weren't placed like I wanted.