# Prevent Float from being placed within a paragraph

Tags: floats, positioning

is it possible to prevent a float from being placed within a paragraph? I know there has been another post ([How to protect text from being split by a float?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25917/how-to-protect-text-from-being-split-by-a-float)) with a similar question, but I would like to allow the float to be placed after the paragraph as well.

This minimal working example (shortened) illustrates what I mean:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htbp]
   \def\a{ I am a figure}
   \a\\\a\\\a\\\a\\\a\\\a\\\a\\\a\\\a\\\a\\\a
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[htbp]
    \def\b{I am another figure}
    \b\\\b\\\b\\\b\\\b\\\b\\\b\\\b\\\b\\\b\\\b
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[htbp]
    \def\c{I am yet another figure}
    \c\\\c\\\c\\\c\\\c\\\c\\\c\\\c\\\c\\\c\\\c
\end{figure}

\def\d{I am text}
\d\\\d\\\d\\\d\\\d\\\d\\\d\\\d\\\d\\\d\\
\d\\\d\\\d\\\d\\\d\\\d\\\d\\\d\\\d\\\d\\
\d\\\d\\\d\\\d\\\d\\\d\\\d\\\d\\\d\\\d\\
\d\\\d\\\d\\\d\\\d\\\d\\\d\\\d\\\d\\\d\\
\d\\\d\\\d\\\d\\\d\\\d\\\d\\\d\\\d\\\d\\
\d\\\d\\\d\\\d\\\d\\\d\\\d\\\d\\\d\\\d\\
\d\\\d\\\d\\\d\\\d\\\d\\\d\\\d\\\d\\\d\\
\d\\\d\\\d\\\d\\\d\\\d\\\d\\\d\\\d\\\d\\
\d\\\d\\\d\\\d\\\d\\\d\\\d\\\d\\\d\\\d\\
\d\\\d\\\d\\\d\\\d\\\d\\\d\\\d\\\d\\\d
\end{document}
```

Using the solution from the post I linked above, the three figures would be forced to be placed before the text, but I would like to allow the following solution as well:

```
FIGURE1
FIGURE2
TEXT
FIGURE3
```

I thought maybe it is possible to place the text in some kind of a boxed environment (page breaks inside the paragraph must be possible).

Comment: It's true, you don't *have* to use the `figure` environment to place a float/figure. Using the [`caption` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/caption), you can place the final figure in a `minipage` *after* the text and use `\captionof{figure}{<caption>}`.

Comment: I updated the example to show the problem without needing to be edited.

Answer (score 3):

Changing [float placement parameters](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39017/how-to-influence-the-position-of-float-environments-like-figure-and-table-in-lat/39020#39020) mid document is a bit fragile, but this works here

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htbp]
   \def\a{ I am a figure}
   \a\\\a\\\a\\\a\\\a\\\a\\\a\\\a\\\a\\\a\\\a
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[htbp]
    \def\b{I am another figure}
    \b\\\b\\\b\\\b\\\b\\\b\\\b\\\b\\\b\\\b\\\b
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[htbp]
    \def\c{I am yet another figure}
    \c\\\c\\\c\\\c\\\c\\\c\\\c\\\c\\\c\\\c\\\c
\end{figure}


{\setcounter{totalnumber}{0}
\def\d{I am text}
\d\\\d\\\d\\\d\\\d\\\d\\\d\\\d\\\d\\\d\\
\d\\\d\\\d\\\d\\\d\\\d\\\d\\\d\\\d\\\d\\
\d\\\d\\\d\\\d\\\d\\\d\\\d\\\d\\\d\\\d\\
\d\\\d\\\d\\\d\\\d\\\d\\\d\\\d\\\d\\\d\\
\d\\\d\\\d\\\d\\\d\\\d\\\d\\\d\\\d\\\d\\
\d\\\d\\\d\\\d\\\d\\\d\\\d\\\d\\\d\\\d\\
\d\\\d\\\d\\\d\\\d\\\d\\\d\\\d\\\d\\\d\\
\d\\\d\\\d\\\d\\\d\\\d\\\d\\\d\\\d\\\d\\
\d\\\d\\\d\\\d\\\d\\\d\\\d\\\d\\\d\\\d\\
\d\\\d\\\d\\\d\\\d\\\d\\\d\\\d\\\d\\\d}\afterpage{\setcounter{totalnumber}{3}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi, I first thought this would do exactly what I wanted, but unfortunately this does not allow the third figure to be placed directly after the text. Instead, it needs to be placed on a new page. This is somewhat important for me as I actually have several of these blocks along with some figures. I want to have the figures between the blocks, but don't want them to split the blocks.

Comment: How do you want it to be placed after the text? it can not be `h` as it has already floated, if it were `t` then it would move back up the page into the marked region. You could allow `b` on the last page, but that would be a bit tricky in case adding the b float pushed some of the marked text over to the next page which is not allowed.

Comment: I would like to have it like this: (FLOAT) TEXT (FLOAT) TEST (FLOAT) ... where TEXT are the paragraphs, and (FLOAT) is a place where a float is allowed. Page breaks are allowed within the text paragraphs.

Comment: But latex floats go at top or bottoms of pages they don't go mid-page except for the special case of `h` where the float can go at the point it is defined.  Why do you need floats at all why not just use captioned tables (or images) and have them  and the text appear in the order they appear in the source. It appears that you don't want any of the  properties of a floating environment.