# Float placement: how can I prevent a float from splitting a paragraph?

Tags: floats

I want to use floating figures within my thesis to improve the layout; however, when the float will not fit in the text, it is placed at the top of the next page. This can often be in the middle of a paragraph. Is there anyway to make LaTeX put the float at the end of that paragraph rather than in the middle of it?

I'm using the `extraplaceins` package and and preparing the file using LyX

```
\usepackage[section,subsection,subsubsection]{extraplaceins}
```

Comment: You can use `[hp]` so that if it doesn't go here it doesn't go to the top of any page but latex can not add a float mid-page if it floats, it has to go at the top or bottom or on a float page so it can not be inserted mid-page after the paragraph.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to protect text from being split by a float?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25917/5764) You may have to add [`flafter`](http://ctan.org/pkg/flafter) to your LaTeX Preamble and insert ERTs to specify `\FloatBarrier`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `[hp]` so that if it doesn't go here it doesn't go to the top of any text page, but latex may place it on a float page that doesn't contain paragraphs from the main text flow. LaTeX's output routine always places floats at the top or bottom of text pages, so can not add it after a partial paragraph at the top of a page.