# In LyX, how do I stop a figure float appearing inside a enumerate list

Tags: floats, lyx, enumerate

I have a enumerate list which splits over into the next page. My issue is a figure float from earlier in the text appears at the top of the new page and breaks up the enumerated list, which is unpleasant to look at.

How can I block together or protect the {list} so that it does not get spliced by a figure float.

I don't mind how the figure appears there I would rather the list appear either side of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `placeins` package gives the command `\FloatBarrier`, which will make sure any floats will be put in before this point.

The `flafter` package ensures that floats don't appear until after they appear in the code.

You could move the definition of the float to after your list. (These are the LaTeX solutions, I assume they'd work for Lyx.)

(Taken from [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25917/how-to-protect-text-from-being-split-by-a-float))