# Do not place here

Tags: floats

In a document containing theorems with proofs and floating objects, LaTeX automatically places the floating object between the theorem and its proof (because the proof is on the next page). Is there a way to tell LaTeX not to place floating objects between the theorem and the proof.

Comment: Short answer: no.  Longer answer, hmm there isn't a longer answer. (You can use [bp] to stop it coming at the top of any page, or move it in the source to after the proof if you want it at the top of a later page)

Comment: You could use the `placeins` package and put a `\FloatBarrier` before your theorem, such that all unprocessed floats are being placed, before typesetting theorem and proof.

Comment: this looks quite a lot like [How to protect text from being split by a float?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25917)