# Avoid splitting of itemize lists by floats?

Tags: floats, itemize

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to protect text from being split by a float?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25917/how-to-protect-text-from-being-split-by-a-float)

I have a list constructed using `itemize` which is split by a figure. Is it possible to prevent the figure from splitting the list of items?

Comment: It'll be easier to help you if you post a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that).

Comment: [How to protect text from being split by a float?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25917/how-to-protect-text-from-being-split-by-a-float) could be a duplicate. Please have a look on it. [How to avoid that listings are interrupted by floats?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14522/how-to-avoid-that-listings-are-interrupted-by-floats) might also be useful.